# Retrofit 2 Not populating the RecyclerView

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit 2 to fetch data (JSON) from Flickr API, my app crash, and I don't get any error in the log, only this

> (E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout)

, 
its the first time I'm using rtf2, I want to ask if my BASE_URL AND GET are correct.

[API URL](https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=2c4de907e1434d1390ab3c09461619b4&user_id=49191827%40N00&extras=&format=json&nojsoncallback=1)

BASE_URL : https://www.flickr.com/

```
@GET : /services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=2c4de907e1434d1390ab3c09461619b4&user_id=49191827%40N00&extras=&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"
```

I'm studying [this](https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23) tutorial

Thank you!

Comment: You are not attaching your `Adapter` to `RecyclerView`

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with retrofit. Your issue seems to be related to you not attaching the recyclerview adapter to the recyclerview.

Moreover, the above should not crash the app. Can you show your stacktrace?